# IIS7 - Basic Authentication Module missing?

Tags: iis-7

I'd like to use basic HTTP authentication to keep people out of our dev site instance since it is unfortantly exposed to the wild internet.

However, in IIS7, the only authentication modes listed are Forms, Anonymous and Impersonation.

Where did the "Basic Authentication" module go, and how can I get it back?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You might have to install the basic authentication module for IIS.

For vista it is:
Control Panel -> Programs -> Turn Windows features on or off

For Server 2008: 
Server Manager -> Roles -> Web Server -> Add Role Services

Then in the treeview it is:
Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Security - > Basic Authentication

Click the checkbox and install.  Then you should be able to see the basic authentication option.

Comment: Note that you'll likely need to close and reopen IIS Manager to see the new authentication option.

Answer (score 1):

To add using PowerShell you can use the following command:

```
Import-Module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature Web-Basic-Auth
```

Comment: In Windows Server 2012, this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

TechNet is your friend :)

[IIS 7.0: Configure Basic Authentication](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772009(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Where is says to select Basic Authentication - that option is missing :|

Comment: Open Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn windows features on or off -> Scroll down to IIS, expand all of the nodes to find the ‘Security’ node within there and look for “basic authentication”. Check the box, then click OK.

Comment: The TechNet page doesn't mention the fact that the feature has to be enabled before it can be configured.